# Screen section as400 not accepted

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I'm trying to learn COBOL on AS400. I get a problem when I write `SCREEN SECTION.`

I get this message (LNC1030 cause "SCREEN INCORRECT") Although I have looked if I have made an error while writing `SCREEN SECTION`.

This is the code :

```
**==================================================== 
 SCREEN SECTION. *>This line generates a error 
**====================================================
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
**========================================================
 DISPLAY "Bonjour tout le monde" "Hello World".
 exit program.
```

Comment: I suspect this is a syntax error but would need to see more of the original code to help

Comment: show your code..

Comment: Before "PROCEDURE DIVISION" I don't believe "SCREEN SECTION" is an expected/recognized section name (like "WORKING-STORAGE SECTION" or "LINKAGE SECTION").  For DISPLAY, it isn't necessary to define a screen.  Try removing it entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the additional information.  I got your program to compile and run as follows:

```
  **===========================================      
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.                               
  **===========================================      
       DISPLAY "BONJOUR TOUT LE MONDE" "HELLO WORLD".
       EXIT PROGRAM.
```

Editing in SEU as source type "CBL", the editor would not even allow "SCREEN SECTION" where it was initially placed in Area-A. It also recognized that the "DISPLAY" and "EXIT PROGRAM" statements had to be indented to Area-B.

A "SCREEN SECTION", if it were necessary and defined, would be a paragraph in Area-B as part of of the program (PROCEDURE DIVISION) logic. I found this guide to the structure of an ILE COBOL program that might be helpful: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzase/sc09254033.htm
(as your example demonstrates, not all of the pieces are necessary, but many are good practice)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Richard. I understand now why it wouldn't run